# HSQL (Hypersonic SQL) throwing error when using NLSSORT

Tags: java, oracle, unit-testing

I am getting the following error when running unit tests using HSQL.

> Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or
>   object not found: NLSSORT ; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not
>   found: NLSSORT

I have selected to use to oracle dialect in the HSQL configurations which work well for other Oracle specific queries.

Here is the query that is failing;

```
 select COUNTRY_CODE, COUNTRY_E_DESC

                from COUNTRY

                order by nlssort(COUNTRY_E_DESC ,'NLS_SORT=BINARY_AI')
```

Is there another configuration I need to set to get HSQL to use NLSSORT?

Answer (score 0):

NLSSORT comes from MySql, and it is proprietary syntax.
It is not supported by all database in the world.

Refer to the HSQL documentation:
http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_ordering

```
<order by clause> ::= ORDER BY <sort specification> [ { <comma> <sort specification> }... ]
<sort specification> ::= <value expression> [ <collate clause> ] [ ASC | DESC ] [ NULLS FIRST | NULLS LAST ]
```

and then:

```
<collate clause> ::= COLLATE <collation name>
```

An example from the documentation:

```
 SELECT id, lastname FROM customer ORDER BY lastname COLLATE "English"
```

---

Use `COLLATE` instead of `NLSSORT`